# How to manually install wpasupplicant 2.1?

Tags: wireless, software-installation, wpa-supplicant

I'm trying to install wpasupplicant 2.1 because I'm having some problems with 2.4 . I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant=2.1-0ubuntu7
```

But that `wpasupplicant` version cannot be found. I found the archives and downloaded manually `wpa_supplicant-2.1.tar.gz`. How would I go about installing it though? I couldn't find any comprehensible instructions online and am newbie.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? Maybe you could download the deb file from http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/wpasupplicant/download and install that.

Answer (score -1):

You can install by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant
```

Download the wpasupplicant from [here](http://hostap.epitest.fi/wpa_supplicant/):

Do the required changes in *.config*

install wpa_supplicant by:

```
 #make && make install
```

Configuration

Set **wpa_supplicant.conf** to the following:

More Detail [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/basicnet/wpa_supplicant.html):

Comment: I believe that `sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant` simply installs the latest version from the Ubuntu repositories. It does not compile the tar.gz.

Comment: Given link for Tar file and it can be compile read first properly before giving downvote.

Comment: Does or does not the command `sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant` simply install the latest version, *not* 2.1, from the repos? That is not what he is trying to accomplish. That is what he is trying to overcome. Please see: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15372885/